# Anime identification request about guy with invisible pills (hentai)

Tags: identification-request

I'll just describe it as I don't want to post NSFW links (plus I can't find them anyways).
I just saw it on some fishy site somewhere, and the story was interesting, at least for me.
The video was raw, so I didn't understand any of it.

This is what I remember of it:

- The MC is a guy who is a store employee together with two girls
- One girl is a harsh manager of sorts, the other a shy-type
- One day an old guy appeared suddenly, giving him pills that can make him invisible
- He tested it and sure enough, he became invisible
- Forgot some of the "meaty" parts, but one involved doing it with the harsh manager, and one doing it with the shy-type. There were other girls involved, but I can't remember them.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: It sounds like [The Invisible Stud](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3888/Toumei_Ningen_%28OVA%29). That what Google answered me.

Comment: +1 for a Hentai ID Request that didn't post an uncensored NSFW image, a link to a blatant porn site or use porn language. infact if it was possible i would give another +1 for the absence of any explicit language, correct or otherwise

Comment: @mirroroftruth I totally forgot to Google it.

Comment: @Memor-X I figured that it's quite embarrassing to post an NSFW link or to even ask about hentai, so I checked the meta first. Sure enough, nothing mentions of hentai not being allowed, as long as it's a clean post. I'm grateful that you appreciate my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP describe It sounds like [The Invisible Stud](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3888/Toumei_Ningen_%28OVA%29/) contain [nsfw](/questions/tagged/nsfw) image.

**Synopsis**:

> Mie happened to pick up medicine that an old man dropped. When he took the medicine, his figure disappeared. Soon he went to a public bath to peep, and began to molest. Then, he went to an all-girls school.

And there only three character Fujisawa , Mei and Suzu.

Comment: This is correct. The other girls involved were probably from that all-girls school and the bath. My memory served me wrong thinking that MC was given the pills (because I watched it raw, I guess), but that girl from the link looked familiar.